# Add custom type to Known Types of SuspensionManager

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, xml-serialization

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app in which I have passed a custom type to page navigation but when I press home button it crashes because it is unable to serialize the object being passed at navigation. By looking at few links all I could come up with is

```
[DataContract()]
[KnownType(typeof(OrderItem))]
[KnownType(typeof(OrderHistoryDataModel))]
public class OrderHistoryModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool success { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<OrderHistoryDataModel> data { get; set; }
}

[DataContract()]
public class OrderItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string store_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string order_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string device_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string device_token { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string platform { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string variant_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string weight { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string mrp_price { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string price { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string discount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string unit_type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string product_brand { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string subcategory_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string subcategory_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string category_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string product_image { get; set; }
}

[DataContract()]
[KnownType(typeof(OrderItem))]
public class OrderHistoryDataModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string order_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int paid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string payment_method { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string note { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string order_date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string total { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string discount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string checkout { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string shipping_charges { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string address { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<OrderItem> order_items { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string statusApprovedColor { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string statusShippedColor { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string statusDeliveryColor { get; set; }
}
```

Also at App.xaml.cs I have added

```
SuspensionManager.KnownTypes.Add(typeof(List<GroceryApp.Models.OrderHistoryDataModel>));
        SuspensionManager.KnownTypes.Add(typeof(List<GroceryApp.Models.OrderItem>));
        SuspensionManager.KnownTypes.Add(typeof(GroceryApp.Models.OrderHistoryDataModel));
```

Still it does crash. So my question is how do I add a custom type to known types for serialization?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the Reference in the Header

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

Comment: How big is the data size does it take more then 6 sec?

Comment: I'm passing an object of OrderHistoryDataModel and size is not large. It takes time less than a second i.e. very few milliseconds.